# Does an analytic function maps a simple connected region into a simple connected region?

Tags: complex-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $f$ is analytic, say, in $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose  $\Omega$ is a **bounded** simple connected open domain whose boundary we denote as $\Gamma$, then is $f(\Omega)$ also a simple connected domain whose boundary is $f(\Gamma)$?

I think $f(\Omega)$ is also connected becasue the continuity of $f$ suffices,
but I'm not sure whether $f(\Omega)$ is **simple connected** and whether $f(\Gamma)$ will be the boundary of the domain.

Sorry for the above too simple question...

Now I put an additional condition on $f$, assuming that $f$ maps $\Gamma$ injectively into $f(\Gamma)$, then what can we say about $f(\Omega)$ ?
Or, what if $f$ is injective on $\overline{\Omega}$ ?

Comment: Think about $f(z)=z^2$.

Comment: ... or $f(z)=e^z$.

Comment: @nsrt, hm... (way too trivial for you :-). Let's take $f(z):=z^5$ where domain is restricted $\Re(z) > 0$.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that we assume $\Omega$ a bounded domain

Comment: How about the disk $\lvert z \rvert < 2\pi$ under the function $f(z) = e^z$?

Comment: Why was name @booksee missing in the previous comment (on two attempts)?

Comment: @wlod: the question owner is automatically notified by any comment on the question. The software strips superfluous @ s.

Comment: @MartianInvader yes, $e^z$ can never be 0.

Comment: @wlod Strange...Their names become plain text, not hyperlinks.

Comment: @MartianInvader I have modified the question, could you help me out?

Comment: Your new condition means that $f$ is a map between open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ that is continuous, injective, and surjective.  Such a map is necessarily a homeomorphism, thus preserves all topological properties of $\Gamma$, including being simply connected.

Comment: @MartianInvader What if $f$ is only injective on $\Gamma$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @nsrt indicates, the set $\{ z \mid \Im(z) \gt 0, 1 \lt |z| \lt 2 \}$ maps under $z\mapsto z^3$ to $\{|z| \lt 8\}\setminus \{|z|\le 1\}$, which is not simply connected.

Comment: What number $z$ with positive imaginary part has square $2$?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake! Should be $\geq$, not $>$.

Comment: With $\ge$ is it not "open". A better fix would be to use $z^3$ with your original set.  Since it is already CW I will do that for you.

Comment: Good point; thanks for the fix.